# C# - Assign Mocked dependencies that are Imported from MEF

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, mef

I'm using **MEF** for dependency injection and I'm at this point writing a unit test in which I'd have to inject a mocked dependency, but I have declared it as `{ get; protected set; }` which renders me unable to do it.

The dependency is imported using the `[Import]` attribute, which means it isn't passed via constructor or anything similar.

What is the right approach, and by "right" I mean it doesn't violate any principle like SOLID and similar, to solve this inconvenient?

Code:

```
[Import]  // MEF is able to inject it even tho it's set accessor is protected
IMyDependencie MyDependency { get; protected set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the class is sealed, you can create a class which inherits from it and sets the protected property:

```
public class TestClass : ClassToBeTested
{
    public TestClass(IMyDependencie mockDependency)
    {
        // Set protected property:
        MyDependency = mockDependency;
    }
}
```

Then in the setup of your unit test, create the object with a mocked dependency:

```
 // These will be fields in the test class.
 Mock<IMyDependencie> mockDependency = new Mock<IMyDependencie>();

 TestClass tc = new TestClass(mockDependency.Object);
```

An alternative - which you would have to use if the class under test is sealed - is to use a [PrivateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) to set the property, or just just plain old reflection to do it.

Comment: If you think about it, my problem could be solved by importing the dependency in the constructor of the class. Would you say the main problem is my class design is wrong?

Comment: I haven't used MEF, but I would personally prefer constructor injection.